# Converting a mutating array to non-mutating in place

Tags: arrays, swift, swift5

I have a code like this:

```
let array = self.doSomething(Array<UInt8>([10, 29, 33]).reverse())
```

the problem is that `doSomething` is expecting a non-mutating array and the `reverse()` function returns a mutating one.

How do I convert `Array<UInt8>([10, 29, 33]).reverse()` to a non-mutating array **in place**, without creating another line of code, something like

```
let array = self.doSomething(Array<UInt8>([10, 29, 33]).reverse().nonMutating)
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass in the reverse of that array? Did you mean `reversed()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "mutating" and "non-mutating" Arrays. The issue is that you're likely creating a ReversedCollection, and you want an Array. You can create that by creating an Array from the collection:

```
let array = self.doSomething(Array(Array<UInt8>([10, 29, 33]).reversed()))
```

Note that the method is `reversed()` here not `reverse()`. `reverse()` returns Void (which you may be mistaking for a "mutating array").

If you mean "I want to mutate an array in place and then pass it to something else," that is two actions, and it takes two statements. While it's possible to work around with extra functions, there's little point to that. `reversed()` is O(1) and `Array.init(collection)` is O(N), so the whole thing is O(N), which is the same as `Array.reversed`. If there is a memory allocation concern, then add the extra line. It is very tricky to pass arrays to mutating functions and be absolutely certain no copies will be made (Swift doesn't provide any promises around copy avoidance).

Typically I would rewrite `doSomething` here to accept a Collection rather than an Array.

Comment: @SpaceDog I would suggest you refactor `doSomething` to make it generic and take a `C: Collection where C.element == SomeType`

Comment: unfortunately `doSomething` is a method from a framework I do not have control. Thanks.